# Does irreducibility in $\mathbb{C}\{x\}[y]$ imply irreducibility in $\mathbb{C}\{x,y\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis

By $\mathbb{C}\{x\}[y]$, I mean the ring of polynomials in variable $y$ with coefficients from $\mathbb{C}\{x\}$, where $\mathbb{C}\{x\}$ is the ring of convergent power series in $x\in \mathbb{C}$.

By $\mathbb{C}\{x,y\}$, I mean the ring of convergent power series in variables $x$ and $y$ with coefficients from $\mathbb{C}$.

If $f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{C}\{x\}[y]$, does it mean that $f$ is irreducible in
$\mathbb{C}\{x,y\}$?

Comment: $xy + 1$ is irreducible in one ring and a unit in the other one. On the positive side, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_preparation_theorem

Comment: @user8268 will it be correct to say $f$ irreducible in the first ring implies $f$ irreducible or a unit in the second ring?

Comment: Every $f(x,y)\in\mathbb{C}\{x\}[y]$ should have a unique factorization (in the same ring) of the form $f = x^n g h$, where $g$ is a _monic_ polynomial of some degree $m$ such that $g(0,y)=y^m$ and $h$ is such that $h(0,0)\neq0$. Then $h$ is a unit in the other ring, but the factorization of $g$  to irreducibles is the same in both rings. (I hope I _finally_ wrote this comment correctly.)

Comment: @user8268 and why is the factorization of g to irreducibles the same in both rings?

Comment: By the Weierstrass Preparation Theorem ($g$ already is a Weierstrass polynomial, so are all its factors in the first ring, and the thm says that everything in the 2nd ring is a unit times a Weiesrstrass poly; see the link in my 1st comment)

Comment: @user8268 say $g=g_1 \dots g_n$ in the first ring and so $g_i \in \mathbb{C}\{x\}[y]$. It could be that $g = g_1' \dots g_m'$ in the second ring and $g_i' \in \mathbb{C}\{x,y\}$. Even though $g$ is a Weierstrass polynomial, it may be that the factorization of $g$ are different in these two rings.

Comment: 1. each $g_i'$ is a Weierstrass poly times a unit, 2. a Weierstrass poly times a non-trivial unit (ie. different from $1$) is not a Weierstrass poly. (In other words, the factorization in the Weierstrass preparation thm is unique.) I'll let you figure it out from here.

Comment: @user8268 I was worried that for a weierstrass poly $g$, it is irreducible in the first ring but reducible in the second ring. But I see now why this is not the case. I will write an answer to my own question and thanks for your hints.